# Objective-C : access properties outside of main UI Thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch

When programming GUI on iOS, properties often declares as `nonatomic` because we often just access those properties on main UI thread (as on Android).

```
@interface TKDViewController : UIViewController
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData; 
@end
```

So, my question is: if I change the properties to `atomic`, so I can access outside of main UI thread, right? If I do so, will I meet some problems?

```
@interface TKDViewController : UIViewController
    @property (atomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData; 
@end
```

thanks :)

Comment: the `NSMutableArray` as _functioning array_ won't be thread-safe even if you create an `atomic` property for its _reference_ – on the other hand, you can have access to the `tableData` (and its content) from another background-thread even if that is `nonatomic`.

Comment: @holex I'm sorry for poor example. so, how the problem is, when I use component such as UILabel ? Thanks :)

Comment: usually the `nonatomic` and `atomic` modifiers affect the direct _setter_  or _getter_ of the property only. the object's own properties are not affected by that – like in case of `UILabel`: your property can be `atomic`, but the current `UILabel` instance's e.g. `string`, `font` etc... properties will remain `nonatomic`. (you can also bear in mind the UI related updates must happen on the main thread in every case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `atomic` with `IBOutlet` will give you a thread safe setters, and using `nonatomic` will give you unsafe setters. 
**So, my question is: if I change the properties to atomic, so I can access outside of main UI thread, right? If I do so, will I meet some problems?**
Yes, you will get some problems, unless you call `[view setNeedsDisplay]` on the main thread (after doing some changes on the background) to update the UI (or avoid accessing it on a background thread). Atomic is just a mutex lock.

Answer (score 3):

Atomic and nonatomic mutators on properties affect read/write behavior. With atomic properties each read/write is synchronized (so only one operation at a time is allowed).

You can access nonatomic properties from background thread and in most cases it won't break anything. You have to be careful with changing properties of UI objects. These changes have to be done on main thread to take effect.